# How can I draw the following plots: Straightening out the boundary and the balls, in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I would like to draw something like the following plots.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the first draw, I tested the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% Point z0
\coordinate (z0) at (0,0);
\node  at (z0) {$\bullet x_0$};
% Circle C0
\draw [name path=C0,pattern = crosshatch, pattern color = green ] (O) circle [radius=4];
\draw[red,looseness=1.5] (-6,0) to [out=-70,in=-110] (z0) to [out=75,in =110](6,0); 
% Point z1
\coordinate (z1) at (-45:-2.5);
\fill[pattern = crosshatch] (z1) circle [radius = 0.5];
\node [] at (z1) {$\bullet x^\epsilon$};
%\node [below] at (z1) {$x_1$};
% Circle C1
\node [below right] at (-2,0.5) {$\bullet x$};\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I got the following image:
[image]

Also I used another code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) circle (4cm);
\draw[pattern = crosshatch, pattern color = green]
  (current bounding box.north west) --
  (-4,-1)..controls(0.1,0.1)..(5,-1)
  -- (current bounding box.north east) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}
% Origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% Point z0
\coordinate (z0) at (0,-0.2);
\node  at (z0) {$\bullet x_0$};
% Circle C0
\draw (O) circle [radius=4];
% Point z1
\coordinate (z1) at (-45:-2.5);
\fill[pattern = crosshatch] (z1) circle [radius = 0.5];
\node [] at (z1) {$\bullet x^\epsilon$};
% Circle C1
\node [below right] at (-2,0.5) {$\bullet x$};\end{tikzpicture}
```

I got the following image and it looks more like what I want:

[image]

For the second image, I tried the following code (using the @SebGlav's answer):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \def\r{1} % Circle radius
        \coordinate (x0) at (0,0); % Circle centre
        \coordinate (p1) at (190:\r); % First point on the circle
        \coordinate (p2) at (-10:\r); % Second point on the circle
        
        % First fill the circle portion
        \fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=olive] (p1) to[out=0,in=180] (x0) to[out=0,in=180] (p2) arc(-10:190:\r) -- cycle;
        
        % Then draw the circle (with the label)
        \draw[line width=1pt] (x0) circle(\r);
        
        % Then draw the line crossing the circle
        \draw[line width=1pt] (-2*\r,0.5*\r) to[out=-20,in=180] (p1) to[out=0,in=180] (x0) to[out=0,in=180] (p2) to[out=0,in=200] (2*\r,.3*\r);
        % The two dots and their labels
        \fill (x0) circle (2pt) node[below] {$x_0$};
    
         %Domaine 1
  \coordinate (c0) at (6, 0);
  \coordinate (c1) at (7.5, 0);
  \coordinate (c2) at (6.5, 1);
  \coordinate (c3) at (5.8, 0.8);
  \coordinate (c4) at (4.5, 0);
  \coordinate (c5) at (5.9, -0.8);
  \draw[black, thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(c1) (c2) (c3) (c4) (c5)};
  \draw[black, thick] (4.0,0) --(8,0);
  \fill [pattern=north west lines,pattern color=olive] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(c4)  (c0)  (c1)  (c2) };
  \fill (c0) circle (2pt) node[below] {$y_0$};
  \draw[->,line width=1pt] (6,-1) to[out=-90,in=-60]++ (-6,-0.25) node [xshift=3cm, yshift=-2.0cm] {$\varphi^{-1}$};
  \draw[<-,line width=1pt] (6,1.3) to[out=60,in=90]++ (-6,0.2) node [xshift=3cm, yshift=2.0cm] {$\varphi$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

I got the following image
[image]

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am stopped by the fact that I am not familiar with the use of tikz

Comment: The only tricky bit are the wavy lines, which can be done using [smoth] on a few points.

Comment: @AlexPozo So I recommend you getting more familiar with TikZ by having a look at this https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en

Comment: what are you trying to represent mathematically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path. There are many ways to achieve this kind of drawings. I let you dig into this starting point, where you can find some explanation. I did not use any fancy tools like `calc` or `intersections` but something pretty simple.

[image: circle and waves]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \def\r{2} % Circle radius
        \coordinate (x0) at (0,0); % Circle centre
        \coordinate (p1) at (190:\r); % First point on the circle
        \coordinate (p2) at (-10:\r); % Second point on the circle
        
        % First fill the circle portion
        \fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=olive] (p1) to[out=0,in=180] (x0) to[out=0,in=180] (p2) arc(-10:190:\r) -- cycle;
        
        % Then draw the circle (with the label)
        \draw[line width=1pt] (x0) circle(\r);
        \node[below right] at (-45:\r) {$B\left(x^0,r\right)$};
        
        % Then draw the line crossing the circle
        \draw[line width=1pt] (-2*\r,0.5*\r) to[out=-20,in=180] (p1) to[out=0,in=180] (x0) to[out=0,in=180] (p2) to[out=0,in=200] (2*\r,.3*\r);
        
        % This node is the dark circle in the patterned portion
        \node[minimum size=0.4*\r cm,circle,fill=olive!50!black,opacity=0.7,label=above right:{$\varepsilon$}] (B) at (120:0.65*\r) {};
        
        % The arrow and the label
        \draw[<-,line width=1pt] (B) to[out=170,in=-90]++ (-0.5*\r,0.5*\r) node [above] {$B\left(x^\varepsilon,\varepsilon\right)$};
        
        % The two dots and their labels
        \fill (x0) circle (2pt) node[below] {$x^0$};
        \fill (40:0.5*\r) circle (2pt) node[right] {$x$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```